# Logging in on a different phone

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been playing on my own phone, but no longer have that phone ad trying to log in on my brothers phone. but i log out of his account, then please login with google and it automatically logs into his without giving me the option to log into a different one! Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

you must go to the phone settings> account> and add your google account. then inside Pokemon Go app will ask you which one you want to use.